# How to enable persistence on React Native Firebase?

Tags: react-native-firebase

I'm using [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/auth/reference/auth) and I want to make sure that the user [stay logged in across restarts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) of the app. For now I've done it through a hack (re-log the user automatically once the app is started) but I want to understand if there's a simpler way to do it.

I see the `setPersistence` method is [disabled](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/auth/reference/auth#setPersistence), though I'm not clear on what's the best alternative...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setPersistence` controls database persistence, not authentication persistence.  Authentication persistence is enabled by default so your user will stay logged in across restarts by default.  However, there is a small delay when the app restarts whilst Firebase is checking the validity of the persisted authentication token.

Check out this Medium article for a better explanation of what's going on: https://blog.invertase.io/getting-started-with-firebase-authentication-on-react-native-a1ed3d2d6d91

In particular pay note to the `Checking the current authentication state` section which explains how to use `onAuthStateChanged`.

I've included the full example here for completeness.

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
// Components to display when the user is LoggedIn and LoggedOut 
// Screens for logged in/out - outside the scope of this tutorial
import LoggedIn from './LoggedIn';
import LoggedOut from './LoggedOut';
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    };
  }
  /**
   * When the App component mounts, we listen for any authentication
   * state changes in Firebase.
   * Once subscribed, the 'user' parameter will either be null 
   * (logged out) or an Object (logged in)
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    this.authSubscription = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        user,
      });
    });
  }
  /**
   * Don't forget to stop listening for authentication state changes
   * when the component unmounts.
   */
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.authSubscription();
  }
  render() {
    // The application is initialising
    if (this.state.loading) return null;
    // The user is an Object, so they're logged in
    if (this.state.user) return <LoggedIn />;
    // The user is null, so they're logged out
    return <LoggedOut />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!